# Use Ruby in place of PHP in Apache2

Tags: php, apache-2.4, ruby

So I know this is a possibility and I have found tutorials that work with older versions of Apache, but I can't find any updated ones.

All I want to do is use .rb and .erb files just like you can already use .php files in Apache2. I prefer ruby for small tasks and it would be nice if I could write my backend scripts in it.

Comment: In short: no.  In more detail... not really.

Comment: well, cgi-bin - placed ruby scripts work, but it's not exactly what you are asking for.

Answer (score 3):

`mod_ruby` is apparently no longer developed, so you can't use it in this way anymore, as embedding the ruby interpreter into Apache via a module is the only way to have it to work like this.